# angular 2 npm install error

Tags: angularjs, node.js

This error log i get when try to npm install start

```
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings: `typings "install"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings script 'typings "install"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings "install"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.    
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IT\Downloads\folder\my-proj\npm-debug.log
```

when i follow instruction angular 2 typescript i got this error, anyone can help me for this error? typings folder not display

okay this is npm-debug-log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\IT\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'typings',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.2
3 info using node@v6.2.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretypings', 'typings', 'posttypings' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~pretypings: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~pretypings: no script for pretypings, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: PATH: C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\IT\Downloads\folder\my-proj\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\IT\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: CWD: C:\Users\IT\Downloads\folder\my-proj
11 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'typings "install"' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~typings: Failed to exec typings script
14 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings: `typings "install"`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\IT\Downloads\folder\my-proj
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\IT\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "typings" "--" "install"
19 error node v6.2.2
20 error npm  v3.10.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings: `typings "install"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings script 'typings "install"'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     typings "install"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: what do you mean by typings folder not display ?

Comment: If the typings folder doesn't show up after npm install please install them manually with:

    npm run typings -- install

Comment: Do you have typings.json file ?

Comment: yes i'm  this is writting code {
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  }
}

Comment: Did you follow the quickstart as it is ? weird !

Comment: @Selem yes we are trying to clone [this](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/angular2-course) repository and npm install fails!  can you check it on your local machine?

Comment: @AliSherafat It works smoothly

Comment: @Selem  but why do i get these errors?

Comment: @AliSherafat I have `3.8` as an `npm` version and `5.12` as a `node` version , try to manupilate them ..

Comment: @Tonykeane Can you include the npm-debug.log?